# docker container network/DNS/Firewall issue

Tags: python, docker

I'm running docker on company VM, the OS of host VM is CentOS 6.7

The problem I'm facing is similar to the common DNS problem, however I'm not able to find any solutions.

So...I start docker container running python image like this:

```
docker run -it python:2.7 bash
```

Then I can run `ping -c 4 www.google.com`

```
root@46120eb4eacf:/# ping -c 4 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.239.50): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.239.50: icmp_seq=0 ttl=56 time=2.371 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.239.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=2.264 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.239.50: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=2.245 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.239.50: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=2.385 ms
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.245/2.316/2.385/0.062 ms
```

which is perfectly fine. However when I trying to run curl command, it stuck

```
curl http://www.google.com --verbose
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.google.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 74.125.239.51...
* Connected to www.google.com (74.125.239.51) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: www.google.com
> Accept: */*
>
```

same thing happens when I make http request in python shell:

```
root@46120eb4eacf:/# python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 11:36:56) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
```

However `pip install` runs without issue

```
root@7fd68dd1f74b:/# pip install Django
Collecting Django
Downloading Django-1.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.2MB 61kB/s 
Installing collected packages: Django
Successfully installed Django-1.8.5
```

The other problem I notice is when I pull out a ubuntu image, and trying to run `apt-get update`, it get stuck as well, not sure if it's related.

The only way I can get this to work is adding `--net=host` to docker run command.
There're some other information about host:

```
uname -a
Linux presidio-client00 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64

docker info
Containers: 27
Images: 23
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-252:3-2095948-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 1.529 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 44.33 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 3.666 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.144 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.95-RHEL6 (2015-09-08)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 1.832 GiB
Name: presidio-client00
ID: ZCIY:EKUA:OF52:3N6Z:YDQB:5Z2Y:CDNO:NE2U:ZOBT:6C67:BB5W:KLST
Debug mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 11
Goroutines: 15
System Time: 2015-10-23T14:04:10.337394645-07:00
EventsListeners: 0
Init SHA1: 4193d771605617409a8d2578127b8fbd5754e969
Init Path: /usr/libexec/docker/dockerinit
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Do you have http_proxy, https_proxy environment variables?

Comment: @VonC that's the thing, I don't see any of those env variables on my host, so I assume no.

Comment: Then: http://serverfault.com/a/177407/783 That looks like a firewall issue, blocking port 80.

Comment: @VonC curl command runs fine on the host, if I understand correctly, docker container by default uses docker0 bridges which talks to eth0 directly. If I can `curl google.com` on the host it should mean the firewall isn't blocking port 80 right, thus it should also within docker container as well.

Comment: I agree (I was re-reading https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/). No other clues for now. (unless this is a port forwarding issue: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/66163)

Comment: I think I hit that link before, that issue was more like cant reach container from outside while mine is the opposite. I suspect it could be a kernel related issue but I dont have the skill set to lock it down

Comment: Right! 2.6.32 is a bit too old for docker (3.10+ is advised)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running docker on such an old CentOS (6.7, kernel 2.6.32) might not be fully supported.

Docker has an [installation page for... CentOS 7.x (kernel 3.10+)](https://docs.docker.com/installation/centos/).

That might explain the connection issue (from within the container)